# Scraping Schema with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, schema

I'm trying to scrape a site that contains the following html code:

```
 <div class="content-sidebar-wrap"><main class="content"><article 
 class="post-773 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-
 thumbnail category-money entry" itemscope 
 itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
```

This contains data I'm interested in... I've tried using BeautifulSoup to parse it, but the following returns:

```
 <div class="content-sidebar-wrap"><main class="content"><article 
 class="entry">
 <h1 class="entry-title">Not found, error 404</h1><div class="entry-content
 "><p>"The page you are looking for no longer exists. Perhaps you can return 
 back to the site's "<a href="http://www.totalsportek.com/">homepage</a> and 
 see if you can find what you are looking for. Or, you can try finding it
 by using the search form below.</p><form 
 action="http://www.totalsportek.com/" class="search-form" 
 itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope="" 
 itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction" method="get" role="search">

 # I've made small modifications to make it readable
```

The beautiful soup element doesn't contain my desired code. I'm not too familiar with html, but I'm assuming this makes a call to some external service that returns the data..? I've read this has something to with Schema.

Is there anyway I can access this data?

Comment: What do you want to get from the HTML code?

Comment: an html table. trying to parse the table directly returns a None

Comment: hmm I still don't get it, what exactly is the website you are trying to get info from? If the info is built by JavaScript `requests` won't work.

Comment: http://www.totalsportek.com/money/barcelona-player-salaries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `User-Agent` header when making a request. Working example that prints the article header and the content as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.totalsportek.com/money/barcelona-player-salaries/"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

article = soup.select_one(".content article.post.entry.status-publish")
header = article.header.get_text(strip=True)
content = article.select_one(".entry-content").get_text(strip=True)

print(header)
print(content)
```

Comment: Your code works. However, I specified your user agent in my own code and it still doesn't work. Must something else be done besides setting the user agent? running a simple soup.table returns nothing where there should be at least one table.

Comment: Also, I prefer that I access the html table directly rather than parsing it as text

Comment: Got the table.... I'll just use your code. If possible I'd like to know why a soup.find doesn't work